# Cannot get Microsoft SizeBench to analyse my 64-bit DLL

Tags: c++, pdb

Using Visual Studio 2017, in 64-bit Release mode, analysing a Win64 DLL I have built.
And using Microsoft SizeBench to analyse the DLL

In order for Microsoft SizeBench to work, you need an executable and the corresponding Program Database (PDB) file for it to do its analysis.

Yesterday it worked. Today on a newer branch of the same executable it does not.
I see

[image: SizeofDialog]

Now there were issues with the Compiler/Linker referring to the same PDB
namely
Properties -> C/C++ -> Output Files -> Program Database File Name
Properties -> Linker -> Debugging -> Generate Program Database File
but I have made sure they refer to the same file in the same area.
Target Machine is set and it is Windows x64

So I am not sure what I have to do to get this working